# Powershell posh-ssh: How to store results of Invoke-SSHCommand?

Tags: powershell, ssh

How can I store the result of `Invoke-SSHCommand` for use after I close the connection?

I've tried 2 different ways:

```
#method 1
$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "ls /somepath"

#method 2
Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "ls /somepath" -OutVariable $result
```

The variable `$result` is empty after both methods

Comment: have you tried this: 
`Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "ls /somepath" 2>&1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked well for me :

```
# Create SSH Session
$ssh = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $PC01 -Credential $credential -AcceptKey 1

# Invoke SSH command and capture output as string (you can return the full object if you like, I just needed the string Out)
$ret = $(Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $ssh -Command "racadm getconfig -g cfgUserAdmin -i 2").Output

# return object is a String - if you want it as an array of strings for each row returned
$ret = $ret.split("`n")
```

Comment: My pleasure to help @Adam. :)

Answer (score 3):

This was working for me:

```
#method 1
$CurrentSession=New-SSHSession -ComputerName x.x.x.x -Credential (Get-Credential) 
$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $CurrentSession -Command "ls /somepath"
$result.Output
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$` from your `-OutVariable $result` and it should work.

`Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "ls /somepath" -OutVariable result`

Your `$result` in the command was being processed, returning null, then trying to output the results of Invoke-SSHCommand to null as far as I can tell

Comment: At the end should be $result instead of "result" that is not a var name on PS.